# apache if header contains then pass it to another url(jboss server)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to check a http header in request, which is received on apache 2.2 and if it contains that header I would like to fire a new request to jboss whose ip is different from apache server's. Is this possible?

I have seen this doc

[enter link description here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

In the above link I can check if header exist, but how to create new request to another server with same header forwarded.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest would send a redirect response to the browser, and it would be the browser who would end up visiting your Jboss server.

I'm not sure if that's precisely what you want, but sounds like what you want is to get Apache to do that request to Jboss and then send the response to the browser. This would be the typical scenario with a web server (apache) and an application server (Jboss) where you normally don't access the application server directly.

What you want to make this work in apache is a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).